# Prove $|-a|\le a\le |a|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Prove that $|-a|\le a\le |a|$.

Can anyone explain this to me in a step-by-step way?, I am really having trouble in understanding it.

Comment: Please try to fix the MathJax and also share with us what you have tried.

Comment: You certainly mean $-\lvert a \rvert$.

Comment: @elaftauqir $\lvert -a\rvert=\lvert a\rvert$, therefore what you wrote occurs if and only if $a\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant
$$
-|a|\leq a\leq |a| \, ,
$$
we will prove this in the following way. The inequality $a\leq|a|$ holds because if $a\geq0$, then we know that $a \leq a$, while if $a<0$, the inequality becomes $a \leq -a$. Since $a$ is negative, this is also true. Hence
$$
a\leq|a| \, .
$$
A similar approach can be used to prove $-|a| \leq a$.